# How to inject custom Service inside of Custom Provider NestJS?

Tags: typescript, logging, nestjs, winston

I faced problem using logger in NestJS, even though the building of CUSTOM Modules and Services didn't take too much time. So let's se how it was built. First of all I installed `Winston/Nest` library to make a **`Winston Logger Module`**:

```
@Module({})
export class WinstonLoggerModule {
  static forRoot(): DynamicModule {
    return {
      imports: [
        WinstonModule.forRoot({
          transports: [
            new winston.transports.Console({
              format: winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.timestamp(),
                winston.format.ms(),
                nestWinstonModuleUtilities.format.nestLike('MyApp', {
                  colors: true,
                  prettyPrint: true,
                }),
              ),
            }),
          ],
          // other options
        }),
      ],
      module: WinstonLoggerModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: WINSTON_LOGGER_SERVICE, useClass: WinstonLoggerService },
      ],
      exports: [WinstonLoggerModule],
    };
  }
}
```

After that I created a **`Winston Logger Service`**

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER } from 'nest-winston';
import { Logger } from 'winston';                         // Logger by Winston!!
import { IWinstonLoggerService } from './linterface';

@Injectable()
export class WinstonLoggerService implements IWinstonLoggerService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER) private readonly logger: Logger,
  ) {}

  warn(message): void {
    this.logger.warn(message);
  }

  error(message): void {
    this.logger.error(message);
  }

  debug(message): void {
    this.logger.debug(message);
  }

  info(message): void {
    this.logger.info(message);
  }
}
```

I guess no need to show here the IWinstonService cause it's pretty obvious.
After that, I imported the `WinstonLoggerModule` into the application module. And I can also inject the `WinstonLoggerService` into other services to catch some debugs.
Like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class DefaultCacheService implements ICacheService {
  constructor(
@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache,
@Inject(WINSTON_LOGGER_SERVICE) private logger: IWinstonLoggerService
) {}
  async checkInCache(expression: string) {

    this.logger.info('Checking Cache...') //    logger!!!

    const value = await this.cacheManager.get(expression);
    return value;
  }
  async setToCache(cacheData: HistoryItemResponseDto) {
    const { expression, result } = cacheData;
    await this.cacheManager.set(expression, result, 0);

    return cacheData;
  }
}
```

Until this moment everything works fine. But I have to main issues.
** The first ** one is how to inject `WinstonLoggerService` inside of custom provider so I could use it's methods for logging errors which may happen during some connections for example **`Mongo DB Provider`**

```
type DataBaseProvider = {
  provide: string;
  useFactory: (logger: IWinstonLoggerService) => Promise<typeof mongoose>;
}[];


export const databaseProviders: DataBaseProvider = [
  {
    provide: DATABASE_CONNECTION,
    useFactory: async (HERE!!!): Promise<typeof mongoose> => { //How to pass logger here? Should i pass service or Interface or token?
      try {
        return await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATA_BASE_URI);
      } catch (err) {
       logger.error( err ) // And how to reach the logger here?
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    },
  },
];
```

And ** the second ** issue is how to log context with my custom logger. I mean, it's one thing to log inputs and outputs inside functions. I would like to log that the service is running in principle. Like the standard Nest.JS logger does it. I mean this:

```
@Injectable()
class MyService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(MyService.name); // How to use here My Custom Logger?

  doSomething() {
    this.logger.log('Doing something...');
  }
}
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me with these questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question how to inject a provider into a custom provider, that's what the `inject` array property is for. So you take your custom provider and update the `inject` array and the `useFactory` to be like so

```js
type DataBaseProvider = {
  provide: string;
  useFactory: (logger: IWinstonLoggerService) => Promise<typeof mongoose>;
}[];


export const databaseProviders: DataBaseProvider = [
  {
    provide: DATABASE_CONNECTION,
    inject: [WINSTON_LOGGER_SERVICE],
    useFactory: async (logger: IWinstonLoggerService): Promise<typeof mongoose> => { //How to pass logger here? Should i pass service or Interface or token?
      try {
        return await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATA_BASE_URI);
      } catch (err) {
       logger.error( err ) // And how to reach the logger here?
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    },
  },
];
```

and then as long as the module has access to the `WINSTON_LOGGER_SERVICE` it'll all just work. [Docs on Custom Providers for more information](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers)

For your second question, so long as you use `app.useLogger()` in the `main.ts` then whenever you use `Logger` from Nest, Nest will properly call to the custom logger you've said to use. [This is described in the docs here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger#injecting-a-custom-logger)

Comment: Jay, thank you very much! It really helped. I don't know why it's so hard sometimes to find these kinds of answers in the documentation, even though they're in text.